# Servlet can be used with an HTML form tag to allow users to upload files to the server

Tags: java, servlets

I want to upload an excel file. This file will be saved in particular path with rename instead of file name. That rename contains name,current system time,and date. For example uploading a new.xsl file it will be saved like this new_4/14/2014_1:57. I tried lot but still am getting problem. I here attached my snippet. Can u tell me where i have done mistake.

```
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>welcome to excel upload</h1>
 <form action ="UploadServlet" method ="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
 Upload a selected file: <input type="file" name="file" size="50"><br><br>
         <input type="submit"  value="uploadFile">
         <input type="submit"   value="cancel">
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
    output:welcome to excel upload

    Upload a selected file: 




package com.bala;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.*;


public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private boolean isMultipart;
   private String filePath;
   private int maxFileSize = 250 * 1024;
   private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
   private File file ;
   String s1 = " ";
   String s2 = " ";
    public void init( ){

         filePath = 
              getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
       }
   public UploadServlet() {}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws                 ServletException, IOException {

isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

response.setContentType("text/html");
java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
if( !isMultipart ){
     out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<head>");
   out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
   out.println("</head>");
   out.println("<body>");
   out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
   out.println("</body>");
   out.println("</html>");
   return;
}
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
factory.setRepository(new     File("C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/data"));
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

try{ 
     // Parse the request to get file items.
     java.util.List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

    // Process the uploaded file items
     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    while ( i.hasNext () ) 
    {
       FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
       if ( !fi.isFormField () )    
       {

           // Get the uploaded file parameters
          String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
          String fileName = fi.getName();
          String contentType = fi.getContentType();
          boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
          long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
       //* request.setAttribute("UPLOAD_DIRECTORY", file);
         // Date date = new Date();
       //SimpleDateFormat ft = 
                 //new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
        //String s = ft.format(date);
       // String filename = "bala";
        //String  filename1 =  s+ "_" + filename;
       //String fileName1 = file.getFileName();
      // out.println(filename1);
          //Rename the file
         // File oldfile = new File(s1);
        // out.println("old file name.."+oldfile);
        // File newfile = new File(s2);
          //out.println("new file name..."+newfile);
         // if(oldfile.renameTo(newfile)){
              //filename = "bala" + file.separator +filename1;
              // Write the file
          if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
            file = new File(filePath  + 
                     fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") ));
           }else{
             file = new File( filePath + 
             fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
          }

         fi.write( file);
          out.println("Uploading the file successfully." +"<br>");

          out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName+"<br>");
       }
    }

    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
 }catch(Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
 }
 }
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException,java.io.IOException {
 throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
           getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
  } 

}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the commented lines of your codes, I think I got what you are trying to do.

> Check if that file already excists in the folder, if yes, then rename old one to something and write new on old one.

If that is the case,

```
File uploadedFile = new File(fileName);
if(uploadedFile.exists()){ // We check if there exists an old file
  String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz").format(new Date());
  String backupFileName = "bkp_" + timestamp + fileName;
  uploadedFile.renameTo(new File(backupFileName)); //If there exists , then rename it
}
//Now write the new file
```

I could not check the code, but sure you could get the idea out of this.

**With your update**

Why not simply,

```
String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat ("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz").format(new Date());   
String newFileName = fileName + "_" + timestamp;
File newFile = new File(newFileName);
//Now write the new file
//Well, writing the file to disk do depend on several facts. 
//I guess you are not asking the codes to write the file to disk.
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better u will use only the html page for **ui** purpose. 
and on back hand side write servlet code.

go through the following link it will solve your problem.

[servlets-file-uploading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm)